# How to use salesforce market cloud source in AppFlow operator in Airflow?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, salesforce, mwaa, amazon-appflow

I'm extracting data from salesforce to a AWS S3 bucket using Airflow AppFlowOperator. To extract the data using salesforce as source, I just use:

```py
task_campaign_dump = AppflowRunOperator(
    task_id="campaign_dump",
    source="salesforce",
    dag=dag, 
    flow_name=flow_name)
```

It works correctly. However, when I tried to run a flow that has "SalesForce Market Cloud" as source, the above code didn't work. I figure I should change the source name, but the Airflow documentation says that only salesforce and zendesk are accepted as values for the source argument.

Is there a way to run a AppFlow flow with salesforce market cloud source in Airflow?